# Dynamic configuration with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-java-config

What is the right way to go from a list of RabbitMQ connection specs to a series of consumers on a publish subscribe channel?

That is, say I have rabbit config as follows:

```
rabbits:
    - hostname: blahblah
      vhost: blahlbah
      username: blahlbah
      password: blahlbalh
      exchange: blahblah
    - hostname: blahblah1
      vhost: blahlbah1
      username: blahlbah1
      password: blahlbalh1
      exchange: blahblah1
    ...
```

I marshal these into a `@NestedConfigurationProperty List<RabbitConfiguration>`. I could write a `@Bean` method that gets me an `AmqpTemplate` from one of those `List<RabbitConfiguration>`, like so:

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(RabbitConfiguration rabbitConfiguration) {
    ...
}
```

I can then essentially map that to an `IntegrationFlow`:

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundPubSubChannel()).handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)).get();
}
```

What, however, is the right way to do this for a `List<RabbitConfiguration>` and have the resulting `List<IntegrationFlow>` handled by Spring? Surely it's not just:

```
@Bean
public List<IntegrationFlow> integrationFlows(List<RabbitConfiguration> rabbitConfigurations) {
    return rabbitConfigurations.stream()
        .map(this::amqpTemplate)
        .map(this::integrationFlow)
        .collect(toList())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to dynamically create Spring beans of type IntegrationFlow based on your configuration properties. There are many options you have depending on how "magic" or "transparent" you want it to be. If you want full magic you'd have to implement a BeanFactoryPostProcessor and register in the Spring context.
Something like this should work:

```
    public class IntegrationFlowPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor{

  List<RabbitConfiguration> rabbitConfigurations;

  public IntegrationFlowPostProcessor(List<RabbitConfiguration> rabbitConfigurations) {
    this.rabbitConfigurations = rabbitConfigurations;
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    rabbitConfigurations.stream()
        .forEach(rabbitConfig -> {
          IntegrationFlow intFlow = integrationFlow(amqpTemplate(rabbitConfig));
          beanFactory.registerSingleton(rabbitConfig.getHostanme(), intFlow);
        });
  }

  private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(RabbitConfiguration rabbitConfiguration) {
    //Implement here
    return null;
  }

  private IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    //Implement here
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then you'll have to register the post processor in your configuration class:

```
@Bean public IntegrationFlowPostProcessor ifpp(List<RabbitConfiguration> config {
  return new IntegrationFlowPostProcessor(config);
}
```

Then you'd be able to inject each integration flow by hostname into other beans using `@Qualifier`, or as a collection, let say `List<IntegrationFlow>` with all the integration flows present in the Spring context.